# Dataflow errors - "IOException: Failed to write to GCS path.." "Backend Error 500"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

One of our pipelines threw the below error. First time we've seen it. We're running over around 625 million rows from a BigQuery table. The job still completed, and was recorded as "successful" in the console. But we are concerned that maybe the file that Dataflow couldn't write to GCS (Dataflow writes to GCS to then load into BigQuery) was not loaded into BigQuery, and thus we are now missing some data.

It's very difficult for us to determine if those rows were loaded or not, because of the sheer volume of data we're dealing with.

Is there any way to know if Dataflow did load that file?

Job id: **2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089**

```
2015-05-28T01:21:23.210Z: (c1e36887ebb5e3b3): Autoscaling: Enabled for job /workflows/wf-2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089
2015-05-28T01:22:23.711Z: (45988c062ea96b38): Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 1 to 3.
2015-05-28T01:23:53.713Z: (45988c062ea96352): Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 3 to 12.
2015-05-28T01:25:23.715Z: (45988c062ea96b6c): Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 12 to 48.
2015-05-28T01:26:53.716Z: (45988c062ea96386): Autoscaling: Resizing worker pool from 48 to 64.
2015-05-28T01:48:48.863Z: (54b9f9ed2402c4e7): java.io.IOException: Failed to write to GCS path gs://<removed>/15697574167464387868/dax-tmp-2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089-S09-1-731cba632206348a/-shard-00000-of-00001_C183_00000-of-00001-try-52ba464032d439ee-endshard.json.
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.throwIfUploadFailed(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:372)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.close(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:270)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextSink$TextFileWriter.close(TextSink.java:243)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:130)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:95)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel$UploadOperation.run(GoogleCloudStorageWriteChannel.java:166)
    ... 3 more

2015-05-28T01:48:53.870Z: (4aaf52256f502f1a): Failed task is going to be retried.
2015-05-28T02:00:49.444Z: S09: (aafd22d37feb496e): Unable to delete temporary files gs://<removed>/15697574167464387868/dax-tmp-2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089-S09-1-731cba632206348a/@DAX.json$ Causes: (aafd22d37feb4227): Unable to delete directory: gs://<removed>/15697574167464387868/dax-tmp-2015-05-27_18_21_21-8377993823053896089-S09-1-731cba632206348a.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dataflow retries failed tasks (up to 4 times). In this case, it looks like the error was transient, and the task succeeded on retry. Your data should be complete.